# sending cookies from subdomain to main domain .net 6.0 and react

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, cookies, jwt

React, that is, the client side is in the main domain. Web api is in subdomain. If the user's login information is correct, a cookie is sent from the web api to the client. When I send a request from the postman, the cookie comes without any problems. but when I send a request from the client, the cookie comes under a different domain. so I can't access the cookie.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61SIS.png)

I didn't give the domain settings in the photo. Although I gave the main domain name from the Cookie's domain settings after the photo, it still did not work. SSL available on main and sub domains.

web api code:

```
 TokenHandler tokenHandler = new TokenHandler(configuration);
 Token token = tokenHandler.CreateAccessToken(user);
 user.RefreshToken = token.RefreshToken;
 user.RefrestTokenEndDate = token.Expiration.AddMinutes(3);
 await context.SaveChangesAsync();
   
 var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
 {
  Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
  Domain = "https://www.batuhanfindik.com"
 };
   
   
 Response.Cookies.Append("AccessToken", token.AccessToken, cookieOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the cookie included in a request across domains, then you need to set the cookie attribute SameSite=none (under CookieOptions)

see this link:
[CookieOptions.SameSite Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions.samesite?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)